# What is this c++ syntax at the end of this struct

Tags: c++

I found this in a book:

```
struct
{
    template<typename T, typename U>
    auto operator () (T const a, U const b) const { return a + b; }
} L;
```

What is the L at the end of this struct? To denote a 'long'??
What exactly does this mean?

Comment: It's defining an instance of the struct named `L`.

Comment: Same as `int i, j;` you can do `struct S{/*stuff*/} s1, s2;`.

Comment: The `struct` is a type, `L` is an instance of that type. A bit unusual to have the full class body definition followed by an instance.

Comment: And to add to comments above, this type is anonymous - it can never be referred anywhere else in the program. And, this L most likely would better be lambda. (Probably what L stands for)